# Como colocar um 'datepicker' numa aplicação Android cujo a página está a ser desenvolvida em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Quero colocar um `datepicker` numa página que vai ser implementada em um aplicativo Android e estou desenvolvendo a página em PHP.
Já peguei várias bibliotecas na Internet de Bootstrap e jQuery mas apenas a de jQuery Mobile funcionou. Porém ela dá conflito com o gráfico da biblioteca `chart.js` que tenho na página.

Alguém conhece uma maneira de colocar um `datepicker` nessa aplicação?
Abaixo tenho o input:

```
<td colspan="2" style="background-color: red; color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;" width="20%" align="center">
    Data Fim: <input ng-model="date" type="text" name="fim" id="fim" value="" class="datepicker"/>
</td>
```

As bibliotecas do `chart.js` abaixo:

```
<link href="css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="src/legend.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Já tentei a biblioteca `angular.js` mas também não funcionou.

Comment: Usa o campo com o tipo `date`, isso vai fazer o android abrir o datepicker nativo do sistema.

Comment: tentei também com type date não funciona

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar isso:

```
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Data Fim: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
```

Fonte: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/